# Video thumbnails not getting displayed in list view

Tags: android, android-video-player

I have developed application which gets the url of video from the database from the server.And plays the video when the user selects the video from listview.
I am able to display the link of the url but unable to get the thumbnail for the video from the url. Heres the code what i have done.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {

                row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, null,
                        false);
            }

            TextView textfilePath = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
            textfilePath.setText(urls[position]);
            ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

            Bitmap bmThumbnail;
            bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(urls[position],
                    Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

            return row;
        }
```

Please tell me what can be done to get the thumbnail. Thats the only thing remaining to complete my app.

Comment: Where is your Video coming from?

Comment: Video is stored in www folder. I am able to play the video as well, just that am unable to make thumbnail from video url. The `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(urls[position],
                    Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);` gives null

Comment: www folder means from Assets or from SDCard?

Comment: its stored on my machine. I have setup a localhost server using wamp am streaming video from server.

Comment: what you tried only works for the videos stored in sd card I guess but am preety sure